# reg.coef_ returning same value twice

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, data-science

created a linear regression model in which tried to find the *weights(coefficients)* and *bias(y-intercept)* thereby running the following code:-

```
reg.intercept_
reg.coef_
```

output

```
array([9.41523946, 9.41523946])
array([[-0.44871341,  0.20903483,  0.0142496 ,  0.01288174, -0.14055166,
        -0.17990912, -0.06054988, -0.08992433, -0.1454692 , -0.10144383,
        -0.20062984, -0.12988747, -0.16859669, -0.12149035, -0.03336798,
        -0.14690868,  0.32047333],
       [-0.44871341,  0.20903483,  0.0142496 ,  0.01288174, -0.14055166,
        -0.17990912, -0.06054988, -0.08992433, -0.1454692 , -0.10144383,
        -0.20062984, -0.12988747, -0.16859669, -0.12149035, -0.03336798,
        -0.14690868,  0.32047333]])
```

getting the same values *twice* rather getting them only *once* and hence having difficulty in summarizing the weights

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your input provides same columns as input for you reg. model.

Can you provide a sample of your dataset?